# Help troubleshooting pbcopy.plist: Trying to copy contents to clipboard

Tags: macos, copy-paste, plist

I'm trying to add a command to copy content to MacBook Pro M1 Max Ventura 13.4 clipboard from a remote server. To test it on localhost, I setup the plist file like so:

`launchctl load  /Users/jerba/Library/LaunchAgents/localhost.pbcopy.plist`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC -//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd >
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
     <key>Label</key>
     <string>localhost.pbcopy</string>
     <key>ProgramArguments</key>
     <array>
         <string>/usr/bin/pbcopy</string>
     </array>
     <key>RunAtLoad</key>
     <true/>
     <key>StandardInPath</key>
     <string>/tmp/test.stdin</string>
     <key>StandardOutPath</key>
     <string>/tmp/test.stdout</string>
     <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
     <string>/tmp/test.stderr</string>
     <key>inetdCompatibility</key>
     <dict>
          <key>Wait</key>
          <false/>
     </dict>
     <key>Sockets</key>
     <dict>
          <key>Listeners</key>
               <dict>
                    <key>SockServiceName</key>
                    <string>2224</string>
                    <key>SockNodeName</key>
                    <string>localhost</string>
               </dict>
     </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Status says it's running:

```
% launchctl list | grep pbcopy
-   0   localhost.pbcopy
```

but when I test it out, it doesn't work:

```
% echo "test01" | nc localhost 2224 <---------------empty clipboard
% echo "test02" | pbcopy <------------------clipboard has test02
```

No contents in `/tmp` files, does anyone know what is going on ?

```
% netstat -an | grep 2224
tcp6       0      0  ::1.2224               *.*                    LISTEN
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.2224         *.*                    LISTEN
% telnet -6 localhost 2224
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```